# change the back background Color of Textareafield

Tags: html, extjs

[image]

i cant change the backgroundColor of Textareafield In EXT js4.2

css

```
 .disable-field{
            background: #b5b8c8 !important;
        }
```

Js

```
 var remaskTextField = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
         id  : 'remasksTextField',
        title: 'Remark',
        items: [ {
            id        : 'remask',
            xtype     : 'textareafield',
            name      : 'message',
            width: 310,
            height:230
        }]
     });
```

i tried the following code to change colour . 
only the first one can change the backgroundColor but the top line of the Textareafield still remaining unchanged .

```
document.getElementById('remaskTextField').style.backgroundColor = "#c3c5ce";
Ext.getCmp('remask').addClass('disable-field');
Ext.getCmp('remasksTextField').addClass('disable-field');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach, that worked for me with ExtJS 4.2, is `fieldStyle` config:

> **fieldStyle** : String
>
> Optional CSS style(s) to be applied to the field input element. Should
>   be a valid argument to Ext.Element.applyStyles. Defaults to undefined.
>   See also the setFieldStyle method for changing the style after
>   initialization.

Example:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.form.TextArea', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        width: 400,
        height: 400,
        fieldStyle: "background: #b5b8c8 none repeat scroll 0 0 !important;"
    });
});
```